# Sum Partition by order by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Oracle:

```
select sum(age) over (partition by snumber order by grades rows between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding) 
from temp_table
```

Can somebody provide me the equivalent code for this in the SQL server? I tried

```
select sum(age) over (partition by snumber order by grades) 
from temp_table
```

and got syntax error

> Incorrect syntax near 'order'

Can't we use `order by` in the `partition by` when using a `sum` function?

Please suggest !

Comment: What is your version of SQL Server?

Comment: @forpas : Microsoft SQL Server 2008

Comment: Check the duplicate link.

Comment: Well, it seems i cant use order by . any alternatives for this in 2008 ?